# whites and other color words as clothing of particular colors

Tags: word-usage

The dictionary lists one sense of 'whites' as white clothing. But no parallel sense is listed for 'reds' and other color words. I am wondering whether this sense of 'whites' can be generalized to other color words, so that 'reds' means 'red clothing' and 'blacks' means 'black clothing', etc.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: From the OED: 2 a. Black clothing, *esp.* that worn as a sign of mourning. Also in *pl.* (now *Sc.*) and occas. with the sense ‘black or dress trousers’. So *blacks* used to mean black clothing, especially that worn for mourning. And "the blue and the gray" often refers to Civil War uniforms.

Comment: Generally, "whites" is a "thing" because people separate their white clothes to wash them with bleach.  The opposite is "darks" or "colors."  You can also speak of "delicates," which, while not a color, are a specific category of laundry (gentler cycle).  That being said, other colors can be used this way if they are a specific category:  a baseball team's "road grays," as the home team usually wears white, and the away team, gray.  The Cincinnati Reds wear uniforms with red lettering, and red socks and caps.  The Cleveland Browns football team, however, was named after founder Paul Brown.

Comment: Tennis whites, let's not forget. And navy blues also come to mind. Both of which are uses one sees unrelated to laundry.

Comment: @PeterShor ~ I thought the term for black clothes was 'weeds'?

Answer (score 2):

***Whites*** is used to mean "white clothing", while ***coloreds*** (and sometimes ***darks***) is used to mean "non-white clothing" (sense 2, [here](https://www.google.com/#q=define+coloreds)).

These uses have conventionalized to the point where they are included in dictionaries. The reason they have conventionalized is because there is a standard reason to employ them: people regularly divide their laundry into white laundry and colored laundry.

The use of 'reds' or 'blues' in such a manner is *not* conventional, and thus not mentioned in dictionaries. This is because people do not characteristically wash just red or blue clothing. There is thus little need for this type of use.

That being said you *can* use colored terms in this way *in specific contexts* where someone is washing just red or blue laundry. But participants in the conversation should know this or be able to easily infer this. Such a use would be an example of non-conventionalized *deferred interpretation*.